# Rails 4 - Font-Awesome CSS problems

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, font-awesome

I have an application that uses [font-awesome icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/).

The problem I'm facing on is the vertical alignment of some icons. More specifically, the icons that aren't being displayed properly are the star, cogs and the lock within [this page](http://societo.herokuapp.com/).

The page that has the elements properly aligned can be  [found here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37944814/societo.zip).

So the question is how can I align the font-awesome elements within the circle's center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS the line-height of .fa is being set to 1.

Since your css is minified, I could not tell if this is custom CSS or the Font Awesome CSS.

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

If you remove the line-height: 1; the icons  will center.

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

If you do not wish to remove the default line-height you can always add a line-height to the .fa-3x class:

```
.fa-3x {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.9em;
}
```

Comment: I don't have words to describe how much I'm thankful with your help. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @CristianoAlencar No problem, CSS is kind of my thing. lol Glad I could help.